# Old machine(P II), grub2 never works... (fifth time). How to set the right config?

Tags: 10.04, boot, grub2, alternative

I gained an old machine, what's config is:

- Pentium 2, 300 MHz
- 147 MB SDRAM (recently extended)
- 3 GB IDE HDD - primary master
- 10 GB IDE HDD - primary slave (recently added)
- 52x CD-ROM - secondary master floppy drive
- 2x USB
- 2x PS/2
- 2x eth card (recently added 1 of them)
- 2x video card (I wanted to try multi-seat :D:D:D) (recently added 1 of them)

Before my tries, there were Win98, what perfectly(lol) worked with this config.

With **Ubuntu 10.04 alternate CD**, I didn't think, that it can be installed with graphical interface.

I thought about LVM .. but no, I thought this is too slow processor. To the primary master(hda, 3GB) I put `/boot` with ext4, after Grub

`error: unknown filesystem ext3`; and swap for the other free space.
To the primary slave(hdb, 10GB), I put `/` with ext4.

I've installed GRUB2 to MBR. It always showed me some error, and `grub rescue>` prompt. Finally I've learnt use that, and I tried to *set prefix...*, *ls*, *insmod (hd0,1)/boot/grub/...*. That last command always shows me *error: unknown filesystem*.

How may I partition this? The installion gets no errors, the `/boot` is filled with data files(linux images, etc.).

Is there any other suggestion to get on with old systems?

Thanks!

Comment: You sure you have enough RAM? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Ubuntu Lucid kernel is just too big for the RAM you have. Give Puppy Linux a look; Ubuntu is explicitly **not** targeted to legacy hardware.

Comment: Thanks your comments. I try Ubuntu variants first, then other disto.

Answer (score 2):

You can install without the /boot partition. I would try installing either Ubuntu or Xubuntu on the the 10GB hard drive, and let grub install to sda. This has worked for me on a PII, 400MHz cpu with 128MB and 192MB ram. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks your anwser, I'll try that in next few days, and write the results. At first with Ubuntu, if it fails, I will use Xubuntu, I have experience with xfce yet.

Comment: I've been tried with ubuntu 10.04 alternate this idea, it was better, then others, because it gone on grub, but now it displayed: General mountin' error, and then restarted, endless loop...
After it, I'll try xubuntu 10.10 alternate, maybe...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience on an hardware that old:

a) Puppy Linux
b) Linux Mint Fluxbox
c) Lubuntu

Comment: Okay, Ubuntu, then X- and Lubuntu, after that Mint & Puppy, Thanks

Comment: Puppy will surprise you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it, Ubuntu will never work correctly on this machine. There is a lot of GNU/Linux distributions out here that are very good on old machines like your.